# Counting success and failed authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I use spring boot 2 in a thymeleaf application

I created a class config for authentication

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessEventListener asel() {
        return new AuthenticationSuccessEventListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureListener afel() {
        return new AuthenticationFailureListener();
    }

}
```

I create two class for theses bean

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}

@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Both listener are never called (success or failed)

is there something missing?

doing same thing then: 
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts

Comment: try implementing `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` in your beans, this might help

Comment: dong same thing then baeldung tutorial. replace: ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent> by ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> success login is working... but not fail